# fuseki different results between mac and windows

Tags: macos, windows-7, sparql, owl, fuseki

I have a fuseki installed on both mac and windows,

I am calling it from mac, I mean one time i call the localhost (which is mack) and one time i call the ip address of the machine that is running over windows 7

the same fuseki version 2.3.1, the same java version

on mach i get:
[image]

on windows i get:
[image]

is that normal please?

(well to be honest, i don't care too much because i will run my app at the end on just one server, but maybe in the future we run some queries on fuseki and some on another os that has the same version of fuseki), so for now i am asking about the reason and if there are some configure to fix it

Comment: Same java version? Can you give more detail there? What does, e.g., `java --version` (or similar) report on each machine? Also, does java allow 64 vs. 32 bit float differences?  (I'd think not,  since it's "write once, run anywhere", but maybe that could be an issue. )

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor *Same java version?* they both give me version `1.8.0_45`. *Can you give more detail there?* Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14), Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode), *does java allow 64 vs. 32 bit float differences*, I don't know this stuff

Comment: one time i had this in python when i run the same code on mac on windows but different results, it was because of localization where the dot `(.)` in some locales considered `(,)`, maybe here the same?, maybe bug?

Comment: Java has IEEE 754 single and double precision types, however, calculations in Java using `Math` can be different on different machines, compared to using `StrictMath`.